# How can I clear all validators when a user clicks on a boolean, then reapply all validators when a user selects another boolean value

Tags: validation, angular7, angular-reactive-forms, formgroups

My application is in angular 7 and is essentially one giant form spread across several components.

In one section, when a user clicks on a boolean input and selects 'Yes', it should disable all validators in a sibling component.  If the user selects 'No' on the same boolean input, it should reapply all validators to that sibling component (this includes custom validators).

Currently, we are able to clear all validators on one selection, however, when the user selects the other boolean value, the validators are not reapplied.

How can we modify these methods so that this can be achieved?

Here is a snippet of the TS file that should clear or apply the validators to each form group:

```
getSkipLogic() {
    this.skipLogicService.getSkipLogic().subscribe(data => {
      (data || []).forEach(item => {
        if(item.toQuestion === 'check46') {
           this.item46 = item.values
         }
        if(item.toQuestion === 'check47') {
          this.item47 = item.values
        }
      });
    });
  }

// clears validators for all controls in a form group
clearValidation(group: FormGroup){
  Object.keys(group.controls).forEach((key: string) => {
    const abstractControl = group.get(key);
      abstractControl.clearValidators();
  })
}

// clear validation for parent financial form groups if user selects 'yes' 
   for any questions 46-58 in the student dependency section
validationCheck() {
  if((this.item46 ===true) || (this.item47 === true)) {
    this.clearValidation(this.financialSectionOne);
    this.clearValidation(this.financialSectionTwo);
    this.clearValidation(this.financialSectionThree);
    this.clearValidation(this.financialSectionFour);
    this.clearValidation(this.financialSectionFive);
    this.clearValidation(this.financialSectionSix);
  } 
    this.financialSectionOne.updateValueAndValidity();
    this.financialSectionTwo.updateValueAndValidity();
    this.financialSectionThree.updateValueAndValidity();
    this.financialSectionFour.updateValueAndValidity();
    this.financialSectionFive.updateValueAndValidity();
    this.financialSectionSix.updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

What we want to happen is, when the user selects 'Yes' on the boolean input field, it should clear all validators for the form group on the sibling component.  If they select 'No', it should reapply all validators to the sibling component.

Comment: do you have a working stackblitz for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

For reapplying the validators you can make use of `setValidators` method in form control. As you have clearValidators function, you can have another functoin called `setValidation()` function where you can set respective validators on your form Control keys. For example,

```
//sets validation for form control
setValidation(){    
this.finanacialSectionOne.controls['<any Value in this control>'].setValidators([Validators.minLength(1), Validators.maxLength(30)]);
this.financialSetionTwo.control['<any value in this control>'].setValidators(Validators.required);
.
.
do the same for all the controls.
}
```

You can refer this link for more clarification - https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl